# Cucumber-JUnit, is there a way to control the order in which @before and @after tags run

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have two @after tags, @close-browser and @screenshot.So, right now when I use both tags for feature file it is first executing @close-browser and It fails in executing after method for @screenshot.
Is there a way that I can tell cucumber to run @screenshot after method first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot should be taken in one of the `@After` annotated methods. Like this:

```
@After
public void finish(Scenario scenario) {
    try {
        byte[] screenshot =
        helper.getWebDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {

    System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        helper.getWebDriver().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is sometimes I don't want to close browser, If the scenario fails the reason for that is for some of my features I'm using the same browser for all scenarios. If i use this after method it close the browser and next scenario wont find the browser session and will fail.

Comment: I don't know if its correct to use the same browser session for all scenarios in some feature files.

Comment: @tosha it is stronlgy advised by the Cucumber best practices to have all your scenarios completely isolated from each other. Saying that, you can still reuse the same session as long as you clear the cookies in one of your `@After` annotated methods

Comment: Eugene if I have multiple scenarios in a feature file is it better to open and close the browser for every scenario? The reason is every-time if we have to open and close browser it takes time.So, for instance if I have feature file to search something in google like first search Facebook,gmail,yahoo and and verify the results for these three searches. Then I would have 3 scenarios. So, for this kind of situation is it better to open and close the browser three times? or reuse the same browser and navigate back to google and start the search for rest two.

Comment: As I mentioned, you do want to run each scenario separately as it is going to decrease the chances of getting incorrect behavior because the leftovers you can have from previous scenarios. But if you just clean the cookies after each session and don't actually close and open the browser, it should not take that much time.

Comment: @tosha no worries. hope that helps. Cucumber is sometimes poorly understood and often used incorrectly. I suggest do some extra reading on this topic. There is official documentation and books like: The Cucumber for Java Book.

Answer (score 14):

There is an 'order' argument that you can pass to `@Before` and `@After` to control order of execution:

```
@Before( order = 5 )
public void foo() {}

@After( order = 500 )
public void bar() {}
```

Before hooks are run in ascending order (lowest order number first), while After hooks are run in descending order (hightest order number first).

Comment: I'm checking for isscanrio failed and if it is failed I'm executing some code ?what if I’m running two feature files the last scenario failed and the first step of next feature will also fails because cucumbers previous scenario is failed. Do you know how to handle that kind of situation?
Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @tosha : please start a new Stack Overflow question

Comment: I did please check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336803/cucumber-how-to-find-if-a-feature-file-has-executed-any-java-method

Comment: Been there & commented

Comment: just commenting to say it is a bad practice for that purpose